# Can you enter the Imperial City, and towns and places like Cloud Ruler Temple?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I feel like this question hasn't been talked about a lot lately and I really must know. When I see the Imperial city all I can think of is going inside and exploring it. I have also wondered about places like Cloud Ruler Temple (I can't find a way in). I have tried to Google lots of my questions and asked while in game, but nothing seemed to have my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The short answer:** Not yet.

**The long answer:** While I'm not sure about the Cloud Ruler Temple, the Imperial City will definitely be accessible some time later this year (if everything goes as expected).

Just today ZOS posted a new [*The Road Ahead* article by *Matt Firor*](http://www.elderscrollsonline.com/en/news/post/2014/05/01/the-road-ahead---may-1st) which includes a list of content that is planned or in the works but doesn't have a specific release date or schedule yet (emphasis mine):

> - A system that allows grouped players to see each other even when they’re in different phases
> - A justice system—steal from and kill NPCs and deal with the consequences if you are caught
> - Migration of European Megaserver to our European datacenter.
> - Field of View (FOV) adjustment
> - Armor dyeing and tinting
> - Two new Veteran Dungeons: Crypt of Hearts and City of Ash
> - New region of Craglorn with a new Trial (the Serpent)
> - Increased ability to pick up items in the world
> - Thieves Guild and Dark Brotherhood storyline and quests.
> - Spellcrafting
> - Horse Racing
> - Dragonstar Arena—similar  to Trials, but built for a group of four
> - Improvements to fishing
> - Crafting system improvements
> - Improved Looking for Group system
> - Better NPC facial animations
> - Guild functionality updates: guild store interface updates, customizable guild insignias, tabards, and guild ranks, and Guild Kiosks—guild stores open to everyone that are available to the highest-bidding guild.
> - Auto-leveling dungeons that level to your group leader
> - Awards when you repeat dungeons
> - **Imperial City PvP dungeon**

In case you're not sure what a *PvP dungeon* might look like, you should have a look at **Dark Age of Camelot** and it's PvP dungeon *Darkness Falls*.

In short: This is a big dungeon with opportunities to level and loot NSCs. However, other realms/alliances might enter the dungeon as well (it's an unlimited PvP area similar to *DAoC*'s frontiers or *ESO*'s Cyrodiil).

In *DAoC* access to *Darkness Falls* is limited and determined by the PvP success of one faction. So there's some added benefit by controlling a bigger chunk of the map and also some added risk: Do you leave the dungeon once enemies invade it or do you stick to it, gain more XP and possibly encounter some PvP? You could even try to fight back invaders, which is something I really loved doing on my stealth character (so there's been the limited ability to pick fights).

Keep in mind that the term *PvP Dungeon* in *Imperial City PvP Dungeon* doesn't necessarily mean that this is underground only. It's just some area isolated from its surroundings (i.e. Cyrodiil).

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I really can't wait to see what they do with it, and this definitely gives me some closure. I was really hoping that the Imperial City was going to be the grand prize for the faction (and the Emperor) that controls the campaign, and they get to defend it like any other keep. Out of all of the stuff I have seen in all of the Elder Scrolls, the Imperial City really struck a chord with me. I hope they keep the interior accurate to what it was in Oblivion.

Comment: In a recent AuA with Zeni, a similar question was asked. It sounds like it will be more like a large public dungeon (i.e. Cyrodiil) anyone can go into at anytime. But that is pure speculation from there vague hints.